# Stop toggled div from moving screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, onclick

I have a div set to toggle hide/show onClick.  I currently have it set to trigger a chat feature but when someone clicks it, it brings them back to the very top of the page, or resets the position of where they last where.  How can I stop this from happening easily ? Thank you!

SOLUTION:  Thank you to everyone who contributed!  While all the answers worked, I ended up just removing the href="#" like everyone said since it was the most simplest method.  Thanks again guys!

Comment: You could just remove the `href="#"` from your anchor.

Comment: That can cause it to not be styled as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is because you have `href="#"` or something and it is actually going to this anchor and not finding it.

So what you should do is `return false;` in your onclick handler. That will prevent the click processing from continuing, thus preventing the browser from navigating to your nonexistent anchor.

Answer (score 4):

Prevent the default action from happening when the link is clicked with jQuery.

```
$('#theLink').click(function(c) {
    c.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$('.link').click(function(ev) {
    if(ev && !ev.preventDefault()) ev.returnValue = false;
    ....
```

as this works as intended on IE<9.

Comment: Actually calling `preventDefault` on the event object should set `returnValue = false` for IE. jQuery fills in the details for you so you don't have to worry about cross-browser things like this.

Comment: @Anthony Mills Thanks for the additional tip!